# Entering Values, and adding specific types

Tags: python, list

Trying to figure out how to work a list of user input integers into separate categories and adding those categories together, and I'm stuck. This is what I have so far:

```
def main():

  again = 'y'

  while again == 'y':

    pos_values = []

    neg_values = []

    value = int(input("Please enter value: "))

    if value > 0:
      pos_values.append(value)
      print('Would you like to add another value?')
      again = input('y = yes; n = no: ')
    elif value < 0:
        neg_values.append(value)
        print('Would you like to add another value?')
        again = input('y = yes; n = no: ')
    else:

      print(sum.pos_values)
      print(sum.neg_values)
      print('Would you like to add another value?')
      again = input('y = yes; n = no: ')

  total = 0
  all_values = neg_values + pos_values
  print[all_values]
  print(total + pos_values)
  print(total + neg_values)
main()
```

I'm just a first year student with no prior experience, so please be gentle!

Comment: Do you have any error message with your code?

Comment: You're resetting the lists during each iteration, move them above the loop. Also please add your actual and your expected output to the question and include any full error messages in case your code throws an exception.

Comment: What do you mean by adding two categories? You will have a two list, one containing positive numbers and the other negative numbers. And return the sum of those lists, element by element.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity, that's just the way I figured out to separate the numbers in positive and negative types, and terminate on a 0. 

error code is: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

Comment: I also want to thank you all for such a speedy response!

Answer (score 0):

Once you fix the logic error pointed out by Mike Scotty, the other problems are really just syntax errors. `sum.pos_values` will give you `AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'pos_values'` (because `sum` is a built-in function and so needs `()` not `.`); and `print[all_values]` will give you a syntax error (because `print` is also a built-in function and so needs `()` not `[]`). Your original code doesn't store zeroes in either list: I haven't changed that. And the output format is a guess on my part.

```
def main():
  again = 'y'
  pos_values = []
  neg_values = []
  while again == 'y':
    value = int(input("Please enter value: "))
    if value > 0:
        pos_values.append(value)
    elif value < 0:
        neg_values.append(value)
    else:           #edit: terminate also on 0 input
        break
    print('Would you like to add another value?')
    again = input('y = yes; n = no: ')

  all_values = neg_values + pos_values
  print(sum(all_values),all_values)
  print(sum(pos_values),pos_values)
  print(sum(neg_values),neg_values)
```

Comment: The code is supposed to terminate on 0, which is why I have the else statement. Is the else statement okay in this case? Thank you for such a speedy response as well!

Comment: Ah, that wasn't apparent from your code, especially as you have another mechanism in place for termination. If 0 is supposed to terminate input, then why ask for y/n? But it's easy to add. I've edited the answer to show how.

Comment: So 'break' is the line for just termination? Thanks!

Comment: You already have a `while` loop on y/n so terminating input on zero is an extra exit condition. Using `break` is one obvious way to do that. It is simpler than adding the extra condition to the `while` loop.